# PHP - Update player level

Tags: php

Ola, estou criando um sistema de niveis
Mas, o nivel faz update consoante o refresh da pagina.
exemplo: Exp maxima é 100% que é = a 100.

Se eu adicionar 1000 exp na conta do utilizador, ele faz upload do nivel ate o seguinte, mas em refresh, o que ira demorar imenso ate deixar de ter 1000 exp.

O codigo é

```
        //update level and exp
    $playert_exp = selectplayerexp($db);
    $limit_exp = 100;


    if($player_exp >= $limit_exp) {

        $levelup = (int) ($player_exp / $limit_exp);
        $withdraw = (int) (??????????????);
        update_Level($con, $widthdraw);

        if($player_level != $limit_level) {                
            echo "<script>alert('Boa! Atingiu o Nível $player_level_total.');</script>";
        }              
    }
```

O meu objetivo é... clacular toda a exp guardada na DB $player_exp, fazer a soma por exemplo 100exp = 1lvl , 1000 = 10 lvls.

Estava a pensar num foreach, mas nao consigo...

---

Agora necessido de 1 coisa para finalizar, visto que ja tenho o calculo para dar o nivel adequado consoante a EXP, agora preciso de retirar essa EXP, exemplo

```
Se o utilizador tiver 1050 de EXP, o calculo deverá retirar todos os valores iguais a 100, o que significa que retira os 1000 e deixa os 50.
```

Estou aqui parado..:

```
 $withdraw = (int) (??????????????);
```

Comment: $level  = (int) ($playert_exp / $limit_exp);

Comment: nao resulta, pois quando faço refresh ele calcula o lvl consoante a XP e acrescenta + esses niveis, mas a XP fica bugada e fica a faltar X exp, o que da novos niveis...

Comment: ok, isso ai faz com que ele de o NIVEL certo de total de EXP. Agora preciso é de... RETIRAR A EXP desnecessaria... `$deposit_exp = (int) ($player_exp - ????)`